# Android: difficulties referencing resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-inflate

I'm still a newbie to android programming, so i tried a tutorial that was to help create a music app. At a stage in the tutorial i was asked to create a new class that extends base Adapter and at a point in this new class i was asked to use Layout Inflater to to inflate a secondary layout, which i created.
But the problem is that from this new class which i created  when i try inflating  or referencing any resource element at all, i get errors.
so my question is :
1. Is it impossible to refer to resources from classes that i create ?
2. Is there an error in my IDE(eclipse) or its just a java thing. 
here's the secondary layout XML file and the class i created.
the java lines with * is where i have the errors.
when inflating "R.layout.song","R.id.song_artist" and "R.id.song_title"

```
import android.R;
import android.R.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;

public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song>theSongs){
    songs = theSongs;
    songInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return songs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout) songInf.inflate(R.layout.song,parent,false);*
    TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);*
    TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);*
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);
    songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
    songLay.setTag(position);
    return songLay;
}

}
```

the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:onClick="songPicked" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF99"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_artist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF99"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

the error description reads
"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
song_artist cannot be resolved or is not a field
song cannot be resolved or is not a field
line 46 Java Problem
song_title cannot be resolved or is not a field

"

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to build your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is R pointing at in your code?

It should point at something like your.package.name.R. If it is pointing to Android.R, it won't work. Remove import Android.R and import Android.R.*, then it should be OK.

Comment: One more thing, most times when i clean my project,with build automatically checked, i get so errors

Comment: Wooh what's solution ? I'm new to using the app. Must be a mistake whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

You can hit Ctrl+Shift+O to organize your imports and if you still have a problem change Android.R to packageName.R and this should solve the problem.

Comment: @Benoist i ran into a little more problem, after setting up the adapter, i called it in my main activity's onCreate method using `private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private ListView songView; SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
  songView.setAdapter(songAdt);` when i run the app its supposed to populate the listview with songs from my device but instead it crashes "unfortunately yourMusicPlayer has stopped".the above code is the only code i added after the one stated earlier(yesterday).